# How to make an input occupy all available space in row

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-typeahead

I try to design tag managing control. I use jQuery plugin [tagmanager](https://github.com/max-favilli/tagmanager) with [twitter-typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js). I'm using pseudo-input element and put into it transparent input.

```
<div class="tag-collector"> <!-- This div looks like input -->
    <input class="tag-getter" id="gc-input" type="text" name="grantCurrent">
    <!-- this input is transparent -->
</div>
```

And when user submiting something tagmanager plugin create span that display submited tag.

```
<div class="tag-collector">
    <!-- this is my submittet tag -->
    <span class="tm-tag" id="MbkVa_1">
        <span>Submited Info</span>
        <a href="#" class="tm-tag-remove" id="MbkVa_Remover_1" tagidtoremove="1">x</a>        
    </span>

    <!-- this is twitter-typeahead wrapper -->
    <span class="twitter-typeahead">
         <!-- a bunch of HTML where contains my REAL INPUT-->
    </span>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden-telephone" value="Angola"> <!-- input to collect values -->
</div>
```

And now the main trouble. I want to .twitter-typeahead with my input always fills all free space in the row.

1) If I use `width: 100%` and enter at least one tag DIV stretching in height. Now on the first row is tag span and at second row (all row) filled by input.

2) If I use constant width and enter tags which total width is more than my input's width than input moves down to the next row. And now I have one half-filled row and one empty row wich is filled at ~50% with input.

Help me CSS masters!

UPD : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLNvH/1/)

Comment: please consider providing a fiddle for future answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float:left` and `overflow: hidden;` as seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/d2YTf/1/

Comment: New span moves down but input always at rigth and top of the container. I need input was the last element in the container and also that input occupy all free space til end of row.

Comment: that's exactly what it does or am I misunderstanding something? What do you mean by "span moves down"

Comment: Ah I think I know what you mean. You want the input to take the rest of the space that is not taken by the container? that won't work when you put it inside the container and restrict the width to 180px. The container needs to take 100%. If you want an additional border around your tags like you showed in your fiddle, you need an extra div around your tags (that one is floating too then). The rest stays the same.